# How can I use split or dissect logstash filters for only the last occurence?

Tags: split, logstash, logstash-configuration

Through the grok filter, I get my URL value, and I want to split it by the last dot only if there is one.

For example, if the URL (`[url][path]`) is : `/mydirectory/image.png`,
the follow dissect works well

```
dissect {
    mapping => {
        "[url][path]" => "%{}.%{[url][ext]}"
    }
}
```

I get

```
"url": {
  "ext": "png",
  "path": "/mydirectory/image.png"
}
```

It works well but if my URL is : `/mydirectory/cool.image.png`

I get

```
"url": {
  "ext": "image.png",
  "path": "/mydirectory/cool.image.png"
}
```

How can I tell Logstash to only split by the last dot and get `"ext": "png"` ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that can be done using dissect. You could use grok to match everything after the last .

```
grok { match => { "[url][path]" => "\.(?<someField>[^.]+)$" } }
```

Comment: Yeah i think i have to modify the grok, or maybe use a ruby filter to have more flexibility